# Convert 10 to bytes, strange result

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = 11
print(i.to_bytes(1,'big'))
```

b'\x0b'

```
i = 10
print(i.to_bytes(1,'big'))
```

b'\n'

It should be b'\x0a'

Why i got b'\n'?

Comment: Because the new-line character `\n` has the numerical value 10. The character at 11 isn't printable so it appears as `\x0b`. But printable characters appear as characters.

Comment: Just a tip: If you want to "compare things visually in the console", use repr() wrapped in print e.g. `print(repr(i.to_bytes(1,'big')))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, as khelwood also explained in his comment, at roughly the same time, here's the deal:

As the `newline` character has a "c-style shorthand", namely `\n`, and also a numerical value of 0x0a, or 10 in decimal, these representations are equivalent. It's only that Python decides to show you the traditional escape sequence.

To be fair, character 11, or 0x0b is the vertical tab, so it could be represented as `\v`, but apparently Python does not do that one.

Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII and http://www.asciitable.com/ for details.

Comment: Sorry chaps, it's rather time-consuming to answer from a mobile, using a slow internet connection. Lots of things happen in the meantime. Hence the duplicate.

Comment: Whn youget to a dsktop - I think it is totally worth putting on explicitly in  main text that "\x0a" and "\n" are representations of the samething, and that the first form is valid as well - just not the default way Python represents the value.